# What is "1" parameter in solc compile function call?

Tags: solidity

In the following code:

```
var compiled = solc.compile(sourceCode,1);
```

What is the value "1" symbolising?

Answer (score 2):

In the [README](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) of solcjs, in the example is reported that the 1 set the optimizer:

```
var solc = require('solc')
var input = 'contract x { function g() {} }'
// Setting 1 as second paramater activates the optimiser
var output = solc.compile(input, 1)
```